# I want to test code using jest with BAZEL, but when I install jest and run rules, everything seems to fail

Tags: testing, jestjs, bazel

### **Problem**

When I install jest to run test using nodejs_test rule, even without a single line of code, right after the installation of jest everything starts failing and when I uninstall jest things work fine.I have checked on different OS and different system.

### **Want to Achieve**

I want to run my test using jest.

---

**Reproduce error**

Create a basic bazel project, write some basic rules, run code before and after installation of jest, after installation of jest, Bazel will fail to build/run rules.

**Dependency**

I am using typescript for transpilation.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, logs can help.

Comment: We are using jest using bazel just for javascript and the only issue we ran into was that jest can not handle symlinks (i.e. it does not find any simlinked files), see https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5356 but no issues caused per se. More information needed here.